# Access Cookie from specific domain Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I have a React app making requests to a Node / Express back end. In order to validate this requests, I am sending a cookie generated by react-cookie in the React app to the express app. In order to prevent duplicate naming, or pollution from the user's previous sessions, visits to other apps, I specified in the cookie the domain it belongs to:

`cookie.save("foo", "bar", {domain: 'localhost'})`

On the server side I am using the cookie-parser middle-ware, and in the route specifically, I am finding the cookie by `req.cookies.foo`. How can I access the domain property of the cookie to make sure its from my domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using express-session instead of using a cookie:

https://github.com/expressjs/session

> Note Since version 1.5.0, the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and writes cookies on req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser."

If you still want to use the cookie you can print req.cookies 
`console.log(req.cookies)`and see the object information you have so you can see how you can access to the cookie field you want